# Can you use a windows enviroment variable in apache conf?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, httpd.conf

Is it possible to include a windows enviroment variable in an httpd.conf?

Ideally I would like to set DocumentRoot to something like %PROGRAMDATA%\MyCompany\MyApp\htdocs.

Background: I'm trying to make a custom apache installer as part of a larger project. I could make installer write an absolute path into httpd.conf, but I'd prefer to keep the conf file portable if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49032) it would appear that environment variable expansion in configuration files on Windows is a valid feature in Apache. Looks like you can use the same syntax as environment variable expansion that you would for Apache on a *nix OS-- `${variable_name}`.